# How to return an object with its functions from API?

Tags: c#, .net, angular

Considering following C# class in .NET

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    
    public string Fullname()
    {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname;
    }
}
```

and the endpoint

```cs
[HttpGet("getperson/")]
public ActionResult<Person> getPerson()
{
    ...
    return person;
}
```

In my Angular app, I have the function

```js
getPerson(){
    this.http.get(this.api + "getPerson").subscribe(person => {
        person.fullname() // is it possible to do this if the function is not implemented in the frontend?
    }
}
```

Could I somehow also pass the function with the object to use it without implementing it in the frontend?

Comment: Not possible. You need to define a `FullName` method in the Typescript model for Angular.

Comment: Or, for your specific example make change in your C# and use property instead of method: `public string Fullname => this.name + " " + this.surname;`

Comment: @Jacek Thank you for your input. It was an example, the functions I use are a bit more complex so I wanted to know whether I could implement it once and use it in both backend and frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. You need to write `FullName` method in the Typescript model.

```js
class Person
{
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    
    constructor(name: string, surname: string){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    fullName(): string {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not.

Think about it as TypeScript code must be compiled. And if you receive code from outside, that code will be not compiled.